# I don't know how to use this angularjs options

Tags: angularjs, laravel, view, model, controllers

I update the question now .

Mi view HTML

```
  <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="eliminartodo()">Eliminar todos</a>
```

Now I send my Controller Angular

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope,$routeParams,Node,User) {

  $scope.nodes = Node.query();
    /**DeleteAll**/
    $scope.eliminartodo = function () {
                $scope.nodes = [];

  };

  })
```

And my Factory

```
nodeServices.factory('Node', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('api/nodes/:nodeId', {}, {
      'get': {method:'GET', params:{nodeId:'@nodeId'}, isArray:false},
      'save': {method:'POST'},
      'query': {method:'GET', isArray:true},
      'update': {method:'PUT'},
      'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
      'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
    });
  }]);
```

In another code I use this and working properly

```
Node.remove({nodeId: nodeId}, $scope.node, function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          $location.path('/');
        });
      });
```

Comment: "I need to pass the model who is called Node", what do you mean with pass? inject? double binding?

Comment: Sorry , I am using Double binding

Comment: update your question and post your html, how are you defining the model?

Comment: I have the new answer

Comment: please stop posting questions as answers, if you are not going to post a final answer update your question.